# TypeScript class property default value not transpiled

Tags: typescript

I have this code

```
class GameManager {

  protected games: Game[];

  /**
   * Clear the list from started games.
   */
  clean(): void {
    this.games = this.games.filter(game => !game.isRunning());
  }
}
```

Whenever I call `clean()` on a new instance I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

If I look at the transpiled code there is no definition of a property at all.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var GameManager = (function () {
    function GameManager() {
    }
    /**
     * Clear the list from started games.
     */
    GameManager.prototype.clean = function () {
        this.games = this.games.filter(function (game) { return !game.isRunning(); });

    return GameManager;
}());
exports.default = GameManager;
```

I also tried defining a default value as an empty array, which is redundant but still

```
protected games: Game[] = [];
```

This had no effect.

How can I tell it to define the array without me having to code a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried defining a default value as an empty array, which is redundant but still

This isn't redundant; it's necessary. An uninitialized property has the value `undefined`, not `[]`.

> This had no effect

You didn't test this properly, *or* you somehow called the function incorrectly. Most likely the former.

Comment: Guess who forgot to transpile... facepalm. Guess I should delete this question, wont really be useful for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a constructor to initialize the variable.

```
class GameManager {
    constructor(games: Game[]) {
        this.games = games;

    }

    protected games: Game[];



    ...
}

const manager = new GameManager(theGames); // initialize it to avoid the problems
```